# Javascript:Json Array Data is undefined

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I  have json  array data  like this:

```
  var arr=  [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "organizationName": "psda",
            "Number": "12345"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "organizationNameEN": "psda",
            "Number": "123456"
        }
    ]
```

AND  after getting  this data from  json  file   i will  use

```
var arr1=JSON.stringify(arr)

and  then  use

    var arr2=JSON.parse(arr1)
var  i=0;
while(i>=0){
var Data = $scope.documentData = {
    "id":arr2[i]["id"],
    "organizationNameGE":arr2[i]["organizationName"],
    "Number":rawData[i]["Number"]
    };
i++}
```

methods after  that  i try  to  get  id `arr2[i]["id"]` and  it seems to  be `undefined` ,it throws  exception like   this Form failure:

```
Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

What  should  i change  to make my  code  work?

Comment: show the for loop

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka I HAV E ADDEDD LIIP  IN GENERAL QUESTIONS

Comment: @titanusititanusi make sure you are having some values in arr2 ... then only you will be able to extract id

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1

actually...you can't access the arr2[i].["id"] from while loop.

so create a global variable and then use it with **this** keyword

### Method 2

if you are using angular framework.Try using with foreach loop.

```
  var arr=  [
      {
          "id": 1,
          "organizationName": "psda",
          "Number": "12345"
      },
      {
          "id": 2,
          "organizationNameEN": "psda",
          "Number": "123456"
      }
  ];

  var arr1=JSON.stringify(arr);
  var arr2=JSON.parse(arr1);

  arr2.forEach(element =>{
    alert(element.id);

  });
```